# How can I simplify my calculator code in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to find out how I can simplify my code for a simple calculator. My code is :

```py
import sys
import operator


if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("Usage Error: $calc2.py OPERATION Number1 Number2")
else:
    operation = {
        "suma": operator.add(float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])),
        "resta": operator.sub(float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])),
        "multiplica": operator.mul(float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])),
        "divide": operator.truediv(float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])),
    }

    print(operation.__getitem__(sys.argv[1]))
```

I want to delete the line print(operation.**getitem** ... and put something inside the dictionary that prints me the value. Thanks

Comment: What directory? And what should be printed? The resulting value from the operation? Do you want to save it to a file in a certain directory? Do you want to simplify the code or do you want to know how file io works? The goal of your question is a little unclear.

Comment: `print(eval("".join(sys.argv[1:])))`

Comment: why not `operation[sys.argv[1]]` or `operation.get(sys.argv[1])` instead of `operation.__getitem__()`

Comment: you could keep only function's names `operation = {"suma": operator.add }` and get it `op = operation.get(sys.argv[1])` and calculate `print(op(float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])))`

Comment: Ok i try to explain better. I try to find something to substitute de print inside the dictionary. When i execute the scrip python3 calculator.py suma 1 5, the solution of the operation must appears in the shell, the solution in this case 6.0 . someones tells me that i have to put some brackets inside the dictionary, no idea what was talking about . thank again

Comment: @blackhawk87 _someones tells me that i have to put some brackets inside the dictionary, no idea what was talking about_ The only thing related to brackets and printing that I can see is the `print(operation.__getitem__(sys.argv[1]))`, which could be simplified to `print(operation[sys.argv[1]])`.

Comment: @furas's answer looks like what you're trying to do.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't meant for open-ended "how can this be improved" questions; if the code works and you want general feedback, ask on https://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not simple - except `operation` - but it has few other useful elements.

```
import sys
import operator

#sys.argv += ['resta', '1', '3'] # for test 
#sys.argv += ['other', '1', '3'] # for test
#sys.argv += ['suma', 'A', 'B'] # for test

operation = {
  "suma": operator.add,
  "resta": operator.sub,
  "multiplica": operator.mul,
  "divide": operator.truediv
}  

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("Usage Error: $calc2.py OPERATION Number1 Number2")
else:
    op = operation.get(sys.argv[1])  # it returns None if it can't get it
    if not op:
        print('Wrong operation:', sys.argv[1], '\nIt has to be: suma, resta, multiplica, divide.')
    else:
        try:
            print(op(float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])))
        except ValueError as ex:
            print('Wrong value(s):', sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], '\nIt have to be float numbers.')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a common pattern involving dictionaries and operators, more like this:

```py
import sys, operator

operation = {"suma":       operator.add,
             "resta":      operator.sub,
             "multiplica": operator.mul,
             "divide":     operator.truediv}

if len(sys.argv) != 4:
    print("Usage Error: $calc2.py OPERATION Number1 Number2")
else:
    A, B = float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])

    result = operation[sys.argv[1]](A, B)

    print(result)
```

Some flaws with your original version were that all of the operations get calculated every time (e.g. performing division even if addition is requested, sometimes causing irrelevant division by zero errors), and that there was no purpose to using functional operators (instead of standard `+-/*` arithmetic syntax).

For error handling you could use something like:

```py
    try:
        result = operation[sys.argv[1]](A, B)
    except KeyError:
        print('Usage Error: {0} must be one of {1}'
              .format(sys.argv[1], ','.join(operation.keys()))
    else:
        print(result)
```